# Android Accessibility Service not receiving Notification in oreo

Tags: android, accessibility, accessibilityservice

I have added android accessibility in my app and it is working fine with pre oreo devices , but in oreo i am not able to receive second onwards notifications for the app .

I can only receive first notification of the app, second notification not able to receive for that app. If i will clear notification from the notification tray then i am able to receive first notification and second onwards not received .

for e.g.

1. notification1 received from whatsapp , service can read it
2. notification2 received from whatsapp , service can't read it
3. notification3 received from Gmail , service can read it
4. notification4 received from Gmail , service can't read it
5. notification5 received from whatsapp , service can't read it

in short , second onwards notification accessibility ignores in oreo from app .

My Accessibility code ,

```
    public class NotificationService extends AccessibilityService {

    @Override
    public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent evt) {
     Toast.makeText(this, "Got event from " + evt.getPackageName(), 
    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
            .show();
      }

      @Override
  public void onInterrupt() { }
}
```

My manifest file :

```
<application>
    <activity
        android:name=".MyActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <service android:name=".NotificationService" android:enabled="true" 
android:permission="android.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.accessibilityservice"
            android:resource="@xml/accessibility_service_config" />
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
</application>
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate the problem?

Comment: i am updating example in question.

Comment: Kindly check my answer.